# monotone convergence theorem - measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

This is the last part of the monotone convergence theorem in my measure theory class.

For a simple function $\phi \leq f, 0<\alpha<1$.
Define a measure $\nu$ on $(X, \mathbb{X})$ by
$$
\nu(A)=\int_A \phi \mathrm{d} \mu(x)
$$

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
\int_X f_n \mathrm{~d} \mu \geq \int_{A_n} f_n \mathrm{~d} \mu \geq \alpha \int_{A_n} \phi \mathrm{d} \mu=\alpha \nu\left(A_n\right)
$$

and thus $\alpha \int \phi \mathrm{d} \mu \leq \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n \mathrm{~d} \mu$. Since this holds for all $0<\alpha<1$ and simple functions $\phi \leq f$ it follows that
$$
\int f \mathrm{~d} \mu \leq \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n \mathrm{~d} \mu
$$

Might be having a bit of a brain fart. Could some please elaborate on how we can deduce that the last inequality holds if it only holds for $0<\alpha<1$. Do we not not need to know if it holds for $\alpha = 1$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The measure-theoretic setting here is a bit of a red herring.  What you really have is two non-negative real numbers $A$ and $B$ with $\alpha A \leq B$ for all $0 < \alpha < 1$, and you want to know that $A \leq B$.  If $A = 0$ then $A \leq B$ just because $B$ is non-negative, so assume $A > 0$.

If it isn't the case that $A \leq B$ then we have $A > B$, so $0 < B/A < 1$.  Pick some $\alpha$ such that $B/A < \alpha < 1$.  Then $0 < \alpha < 1$, but $B/A < \alpha$ means $\alpha A > B$, contradicting the assumption.

Comment: Thankyou! this was perfectly explained

Comment: @Chris Eagle :  I was able to follow your explanation and, as veganwithbeef stated, it was really great. But then I said: "Okay, what about if $\alpha$ was not involved at all in the proof".  I tried to figure out where the proof would then break but I did not succeed. Would you mind explaining that ? Thanks so much.

Comment: @markleeds I'm not sure what you mean by "If $\alpha$ wasn't involved".  Do you mean if we didn't pick an $\alpha$ with $B/A < \alpha < 1$?   Then I'm not sure how the proof would end.  If we tried to use $B/A$ instead of $\alpha$ we would get $(B/A)A = B \leq B$, so there would be no contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry Chris. I was totally unclear. I'm asking to A) disregard what you showed and B) start the proof over but without involving the $\alpha$ term. I imagine that $\alpha$ is obviously needed somewhere in the gory details of the proof but I can't figure out where. Thanks so much for your time and I apologize for my very not clear request.

Comment: For future readers of this thread: I was able to see why one needs $\alpha$ to be BETWEEN 0 and 1 ( and not inclusive of 1 ) by reading ( many times ) the monotone convergence theorem proof in Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis" text. That proof clarifies why $\alpha$ cannot be 1.0. Chris's  nice answer clarifies why we don't need it to be 1.0.

Comment: In regard to above, for people who don't have access to Rudin's text, the answer to the question I asked Chris is at this thread. The question is asked in a much clearer way than I asked it but the intention was the same. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447717/proof-of-monotone-convergence-theorem